# Jquery audio player not working with newest jquery in certain browsers

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, jplayer

I have a small jplayer in a frame on top of a wordpress blog and it was working fine in Opera, Safari, and Firefox, but in Chrome none of the images on the page would load.  I then updated the jquery to the newest version (was using 1.4.3 before) and the page loads fine in Chrome now.. but now the audio player doesn't load properly in the other browsers.  What do I do here?

thanks!
jack

Answer (score 0):

You should look into jQuery Migrate.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate

It is very useful to see what has changed between jQuery versions. It can temporarily restore functionality or tell you which features have changed, been deprecated, or been removed.

Comment: Your post just made me realize that I needed to also update to the newest jplayer script file.. duh.. thanks!